# Flags on a 'possible duplicate' comment remain after the comment is automatically deleted

Tags: bug, comments, flags, moderator-tools

> tl;dr: Flags on 'possible duplicate' comments should be dismissed when the comment is automatically deleted.

I just ran across [a case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36655459/1849664) where a now-deleted comment had a flag on it. Here's what happened:

1. Someone voted to close the post as a duplicate, and left an automatic 'possible duplicate of `<link>`' comment
2. Someone else flagged the comment
3. The post was closed as a duplicate (by the OP accepting the duplicate, so the question was closed by Community, if it matters)
4. The comment was automatically deleted, as is normal when posts are closed as a duplicate.

The flag on the comment, however, was not dismissed. Now it's in the flag queue, and my only option is to decline it.

Comment: Can't you undelete the comment and then re-delete, to mark the flag helpful?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hadn't thought of that, I probably could. Still, seems like these could/should be handled by the system.

Comment: Yeah, normally all flags are marked helpful the moment a comment is deleted (which isn't always the right thing). This should be handled consistently, I think.

Comment: On the other hand, if someone posts the same rude/offensive comment a bunch of times, I wouldn't want flags on that being auto-dismissed.

Comment: To be honest, a flag on a possible duplicate commeny is *rarely* ever helpful (mostly people just disagreeing through flags), and auto-dismissing these as helpful because it got auto-deleted for being closed is probably the *opposite* of what should happen. If anything, it should probably be auto-declined, because chances are very high the flag was invalid if the question ended up getting closed as a duplicate, and that's the only option you're given anyways.

Comment: I just got this today, so this is still happening.