# When comments are flagged, and the user is destroyed, the flags remain

Tags: bug, flags, moderators, comment-flags

This is an obscure bug that only can be seen by moderators. I found a flag on a few comments of a user that were just spam. When I looked at the user, it was obvious he was only created to spam, and I destroyed the user's account, as is usually done for such people. The comments are now deleted, however, the flags still remain, with the only option to dismiss them, which I believe will give the user who correctly flagged an invalid flag. This doesn't seem right.

Proposal: If a user is destroyed, any flags associated with the account should be dismissed and marked as valid.

Comment: related: [Flags on a 'possible duplicate' comment remain after the comment is automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278348/flags-on-a-possible-duplicate-comment-remain-after-the-comment-is-automaticall)

Comment: This is a bug, the flags should be validated once the comment is deleted (by a mod, or through the process of destroying the account).

Comment: Destroying the account didn't validate them, and I couldn't do it (The options were edit or dismiss)

Comment: If you have the option to edit, that would mark the flags as helpful. // The comments of a destroyed user are marked as deleted by 'Anonymous' (aka 'destroyed_user'), @TimPost, not as deleted by the Community bot. I guess that has something to do with it.